# how do i send pushnotification based on version, user status, location

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

how do i send pushnotification for the following scenarios:

1. based on build release version.
2. based on inactive users (i.e, last 30 days not logged in)
3. based on location(i.e, only for uk, or usa)
4. based on usertype(i.e, only loginwithgoogle, loginwithfacebook,...)

Note:

AWS SNS Topics creation based on the scenarios is one way.
 but lot of topics needs to be create

Any other best solution....

Answer (score 0):

Best way is via topics. However, you can send users individual notifications by storing their endpoint ARN and publishing to that target.